# How to display a popup window just when chrome extension is installed

Tags: google-chrome-extension, popupwindow

I need to know how to display a pop up window when an extension is installed.What I am trying to ask is that when I install my extension,at that moment itself, a popup window should be opened asking for a username and password.How can I do that?I am not familiar with this issue.
Here is my manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Calpine Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Log on to calpinemate",
"manifest_version": 2,
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon_128.png"
},
"background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Calpine Extension",
    "default_icon": "calpine_not_logged_in.png"      
},
"permissions": [

   "*://blog.calpinetech.com/test/index.php",
    "alarms",
   "notifications"
  ],
 "web_accessible_resources": [
   "/icon_128.png"]

 }
```

Comment: You have `browser_action` twice in your manifest, you should only have it once.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/29331302/32453

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (details) {

    if (details.reason == "install") { //reason ( enum of "install", "update", or "chrome_update" )
        //Show the PopUp
    }
});
```

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onInstalled

Comment: How to declare reason as enum?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand you correct. The available "values" of the property "reason" are: install, update or chrome_update. (see the documentation)