# Chrome extension popup installation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is kind of a stupid question but i couldnt find any help searching around.

I would like to know how can i make my chrome extension, when its being installed by a user, to redirect him in a new tab with a link of my website?

And where should i put this code?
On the background.js i quess.

until now my background.js is this code

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    allFrames: true,
        file: "content_script.js"
    }, function() {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        }
    });


});
```

Any idea of what should i add??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For "when it is being installed", there is a special event in [`chrome.runtime` API:](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime)

> `onInstalled`
>
> Fired when the extension is first installed, when the extension is updated to a new version, and when Chrome is updated to a new version.

As you guessed correctly, it should go to your background script.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener( function(details) {
  switch(details.reason) {
    case "install":
      // First installation
      break;
    case "update":
      // First run after an update
      break;
  }
});
```

To open a new tab with your URL, you can use `chrome.tabs`

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://example.com/"});
```

Comment: so if i put `chrome.tabs.creat` in the `//first installation` with the link that i want, it will be ok right?

Comment: pefect man!! i tried it in the developer mode and it worked. :)